# How can we create sub-folders under a container my problem is some this different

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to store specific images or configuration files in a structure like this :

/test/images/abc.png
/test/images1/abc.png

**Question:** How can we create sub-folders under a container. In my use case test will have a container and images will be folder and images and images1  will be created at time of store abc.png file.

In AWS it will automatically create path like this and we can store directly.

**below is code that I was trying to do.**

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = client.getContainerReference("test");
String key="images1/746ca358-2c6d-41f1-943e-a6a5ae287826.png";
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(key);

File sourceFile = new File("/Users/saurabhmishra/Desktop/error.png");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
blob.upload(inputStream,100);
```

**and I am getting the following error.**

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specified blob does not exist.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:87)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:196)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob.uploadFullBlob(CloudBlockBlob.java:1035)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob.upload(CloudBlockBlob.java:864)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob.upload(CloudBlockBlob.java:743)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob.upload(CloudBlockBlob.java:712)
    at quickstart.Test.upload(Test.java:54)
    at quickstart.Test.main(Test.java:23)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. Are you getting the error on `blob.upload(inputStream,100);` line?

Comment: yes,I am getting at same line

Comment: @SaurabhMishra Could you please check my answer to see if it helps?

Comment: thanks Jack , yes that helps and i have did that

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storagetest789;AccountKey=G3*****************************w==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        StorageCredentials credentials = StorageCredentials.tryParseCredentials(connectionString);

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.getContainerReference("pub");
        blobContainer.createIfNotExists();

        CloudBlobDirectory subDirectory = blobContainer.getDirectoryReference("subDirectory1/subdirectory2/");
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = subDirectory.getBlockBlobReference("test.txt");
        blockBlob.uploadFromFile("D:\\User\\Desktop\\test.txt");

    }
```

Basically, you just need to get a directory reference with `blobContainer.getDirectoryReference("subDirectory1/subdirectory2/");`, then you can get block blob reference from it.

[image]